# Desativar Magic Quotes GPC

Tags: php, joomla, magic-quotes-gpc

Estou instalando a versão 3.0 do Joomla e preciso que o Magic Quotes GPC esteja desativado. Quero saber como fazer isso.

Comment: Por qual motivo você precisaria do Magic Quotes GPC ativado? Esse [recurso/falha de segurança foi removido](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) no php5.4

Comment: A instalação do Joomla requere isso.

Comment: *Relacionado:* [Usar get_magic_quotes_gpc com stripslashes é uma má pratica para compatibilidade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107623/3635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver em uma hospedagem, pode ir até o arquivo php.ini  na linha magic_quotes_gpc e colocar magic_quotes_gpc = Off que o mesmo vai ser desabilitado na hora, também tem como fazer isso pelo .htaccess, segue o código:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo chamado htaccess.txt, dá na mesma?

Comment: Renomeie para .htaccess e edite, pois o servidor vai reconhecer o arquivo e o executar com as novas configurações.

Comment: Eu fiz isso e ainda assim não deu certo. Pode ter alguma outra solução?

Comment: Tem que ver se não existe algum arquivo chamado PHP.INI, pois nesse arquivo tem o magic_quotes_gpc ou pode ver se tem alguma opção chamada PHP SELECTOR, na HomeHost que é a empresa que trabalho tem essa opção e facilita muito na hora de alterar a versão do PHP e fazer todo esse tipo de configuração. Caso se interesse homehost.com.br .