# Usar get_magic_quotes_gpc com stripslashes é uma má pratica para compatibilidade?

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

O `magic_quotes_gpc` é obsoleto desde o *PHP5.3* e removido no PHP5.4, mas ainda sim pode ser habilitado no 5.3, sei que é improvável um servidor de produção apresentar tal configuração, mas a duvida aqui é mais um caso de estudo.

Costumava usar algo como:

```
<?php
function recursiveStripSlashes(&$data)
{
    if(empty($data)) {
        return $data;
    } elseif (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            $data[$key] = recursiveStripSlashes($value);
        }
    } elseif (is_string($data)) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }

    return $data;
}

if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    recursiveStripSlashes($_POST);
    recursiveStripSlashes($_GET);
    recursiveStripSlashes($_COOKIE);
    recursiveStripSlashes($_REQUEST);
}
```

Sei que parece difícil ter servidores como PHP5.3, mas existem sim casos como este, acho que talvez a preferencia seja orientar o usuário do script a desabilitar, talvez seja melhor apenas lançar uma `Excpetion`? Algo como:

```
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    throw new Exception('Desabilite o magic_quotes no php.ini');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O preferível é realmente de alguma forma informar a pessoa que esta usando o script que existe algum problema de configuração, o motivo é a performance.

Imagine que o script está recebendo muitos dados via `$_POST` (e até mesmo multidimensional), se for usar `stripslashes` para cada nível do vetor em `$_POST` e você tiver muitos dados isto pode fazer o script demorar de processar além de em alguns casos aumentar consideravelmente o consumo de memória.

O `Exception` do exemplo pode ser uma saída, ou até mesmo uma mensagem customizada, todavia o importante mesmo é sempre desligar o `magic_quotes_gpc` e se possível fazer o upgrade do PHP.

### O que é o magic_quotes_gpc

> **Aviso**
>   Esta funcionalidade tornou-se OBSOLETA desde o PHP 5.3.0 e foi REMOVIDA a partir do PHP 5.4.0.

Quando ligada, qualquer `'` (aspas simples), `"` (aspas duplas), `\` (barra invertida) e `NULL` será colocado uma barra-invertida antes (`'` vira `\'`) automaticamente. Isso é idêntico ao que a função `addslashes()` faz.

### Porque usávamos magic_quotes_gpc

A função ajudava alguns iniciantes a construir um código melhor na tentativa de ser mais seguro. Mas, ao lidar com código que utiliza este recurso é melhor atualizar o código do que ativar magic quotes. Assim, por que isto existe? Era para ajudar a prevenir injeção de SQL. Os desenvolvedores de hoje estão mais a par de segurança e acabam usando mecanismos específicos do banco de dados para escapar e/ou comandos preparados ao invés de depender de coisas como magical quotes, como por exemplo:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Veja algumas dicas de como trabalhar com mySQL:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/3635)
- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)
- [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/3635)
- [Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/3635)
- [O que é o ponto de interrogação em uma query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22621/3635)
- [Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50839/3635)

### Porque não devemos usar magic_quotes_gpc

- Portabilidade, pois se o `magic_quotes_gpc` esteja ligado ou desligado isto pode afetar a portabilidade do código, por exemplo, novas versões do PHP, a partir da 5.4 mesmo ligando no *php.ini* o `magic_quotes_gpc` você não irá conseguir usar pois ele foi removido.
- Performance, quando ligado ele irá escapar todos os dados de `GET`, `POST`, `COOKIE` e `REQUEST` e isto pode ser um pouco custoso ao servidor dependendo da quantidade dados que por exemplo o `POST` transporta e também em caso de arrays multidimensionais (que é suportado pelo `GET` e pelo `POST`).
- É inconveniente, pois nem todos lugares aonde usaremos os dados precisam ser escapados e isto pode causar alguns problemas, isto irá lhe obrigar a fazer o uso excessivo do `stripslashes`.

### Desabilitando

Se estiver usando o PHP5.4+ não precisa se preocupar em desabilitar pois ele já foi removido, no entanto se não tiver a possibilidade de fazer o upgrade em seu servidor ainda então você terá que editar o *php.ini* editando as seguintes `flags` assim:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc=Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime=Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase=Off
```

### Documentação

- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.why.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: Acredite se quiser, [Desativar Magic Quotes GPC](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104438/91), não acredito que os desenvolvedores estejam a par sobre segurança :P. magic_quotes_gpc e register globals são dois recursos totalmente duvidosos. +1

Comment: @rray Realmente é um recurso duvidoso, eu não sei se ele editou a pergunta, mas lá ele pede "desativar", se o joomla pede pra desativar é provavel que ele já trabalhe com alguma segurança?