# Resultado mySQL vindo com as barras

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou usando o http://summernote.org/, e quando eu envio alguma coisa pro banco de dados, por exemplo, se eu adicionar essa tag HTML `<img = src="http://link">` no editor, e enviar pro banco de dados, ele salva assim  `<img ==\"\" src=\"http://link\">` e dessa forma quando eu seleciono ela para exibir no frontend, por causa das barras ele não exibe a imagem, e para enviar pro banco de dados eu fiz assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cadastrar'):
    $dE =    $datahj;
    $msg =   $_POST['aviso'];

    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];

      $dados_cadastrar = array(
      'data' => $dE,
      'autor' => 'WEnder T',
      'assunto' => $msg,
      'msg' => $w,
      'tag' => '',
      'curto' => '',
      'capa' => '',
      'ads' =>  1
      );
      if($site->inserir('postagem', $dados_cadastrar)){
      echo 'ok';


      }else{
      echo 'erro';
      }

    endif;
```

A função de inserir PHP:

```
//metodo de insert
    public function inserir($tabela, $dados) {


        $pegarCampos = array_keys($dados);
        $contarCampos = count($pegarCampos);
        $pegarValores = array_values($dados);
        $contarValores = count($pegarValores);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (";

        if ($contarCampos == $contarValores) {
            foreach ($pegarCampos as $campo) {

                $sql .= $campo . ', ';

            }
            $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
            $sql .= "VALUES (";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $contarValores; $i++) {
                $sql .= "?, ";
                $i;
            }

            $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $inserir = self::conn()->prepare($sql);
            if ($inserir->execute($pegarValores)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Como eu posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Bem-Vindo ao Stack Overflow. Você pode gravar assim: `<img src='http://link'>`, deve resolver o problema de forma simples. Para tranformar `<img src="http://link">` use: `str_replace("\"", "'", "<img src=\"http://link\">");`

Comment: E um sistema de postagem que preciso enviar pelo o formulario e quando eu envio da forma que você menciona ele salva assim no banco 

<img src=\"http://www.mensagenscomamor.com/images/interna/new/imagens_boa_noite.jpg\">, eu preciso escapa antes de enviar pro banco de dados e evitar SQLI

Comment: Como eu citei anteriormente, antes de gravar você pode substituir `\"` por `'` assim ao resgatar não vai ter problema, para substituir usar o replace pode dar certo: `str_replace("\"", "'", "<img src=\"http://link\">");`

Comment: Desa forma , a noticia que posto com tags html fico tudo quebrado .

Comment: Errei no replace, seria assim: `str_replace("\\\"", "'", "<img src=\"http://link\">");` ele retiraria o `\"` e trocaria por `'` assim tiranco o problema na leitura, se não for isso eu não entendi a sua pergunta, esclareça mais.

Comment: POWWWWWWWWWWWWW , VALEWWW D++ MANO :) AGORA SIM FUNCIONO COMO EU QUERIA

Comment: **Relacionado** [Usar get_magic_quotes_gpc com stripslashes é uma má pratica para compatibilidade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107623/3635) ?

Answer (score 3):

Só para deixar uma resposta final...

Basta manipular a `string` rebebida antes de salva-la no banco de dados, transformando `\"` em `'` pois o HTML também interpreta aspas simples. O modo mais simples é usar a função [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), ficando assim:

```
 str_replace("\\\"", "'", "<img src=\"http://link\">");
 /*
     \\ quebra a \ e \" quebra as apas simples, juntando os dois,
     a função irá trocar todos \" por ', poderia usar '\"' no lugar de "\\\""
 */
```